# Where is it stated that the socket.recv() call returns the empty bytes object if the other end of the stream has called socket.close()?

Tags: python, sockets

I've been skimming [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), but can't seem to find specific details like the above. Where are such details listed?

Comment: *"The return value is a bytes object representing the data received"* - if no data is received, what other than an empty bytes object would you expect?

Comment: But the socket is blocking forever on `recv()`, but if the other end is closed it doesn't ?

Comment: Well, that's how it works in other languages and in Linux/Windows API.  If the the peer closes a TCP connection, recv() returns 'immediately' with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the documentation, the below is the closest thing to documentation I could get.

From [Python documentation -](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) -

> The Python interface is a straightforward transliteration of the Unix
>   system call and library interface for sockets

And from [Unix documentation for recv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) , under the section *Return value* -

> When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the
>   return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

And when you convert the 0 to a bytes object, you get an empty bytes object. Example -

```
>>> bytes(0)
b''
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I was hoping for a more rigoeously and well documented Python documentation.